# Laravel 5.6 Event Broadcasting

Tags: android, ios, laravel, socket.io, laravel-5.6

How to implement event broadcasting without pusher? 
I use presence channels and my Api uses laravel passport. And i set `BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis`
Can I like the laravel echo server to use without laravel echo on the client because my clients are ios / android applications
on the web part I test id but not work

```
<script src="http://my.local:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://my.local:6001', {
        extraHeaders: {
            Authorization: "Bearer someRandomString"
        }
    })

    // socket.join('rooms.1')
    socket.on('rooms.1:App\\Events\\RoomCreated', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
</script>
```

my event

```
public function __construct(Room $room)
{
    $this->room = $room;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('rooms.' . $this->room->category_id);
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'room.created';
}
```

How can this be done?

UPD

I was able to connect to a presence channel

```
var options = {
        auth: {
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer someRandomString'}
        }
    }
    var socket = io('http://my.local:6001', options)

    socket.emit('subscribe', {
        channel: 'presence-rooms.1',
        auth: options.auth
    }).on('room.created', function (channel, data) {

        console.log('data: ' + data)
    })
```

but my `on('room.created')...` not working how to solve?

UPD2

`on('App\\Events\\RoomCreated')...` worked but why `room.created` doesnt work?